# Infinitely generated torsion free modules over PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a PID and $\mathbf{V}$ a torsion-free $R$-module, not necessarily finitely generated. If I understand it correctly, every rank 1 submodule of $\mathbf{V}$ is isomorphic to a submodule of $Q(R)$, the fraction field. Then $\mathbf{V}$ is a sum of a family of pairwise trivially intersecting rank 1 submodules and so on.

*Question:* Where can I find this written clearly and readably for a pedestrian like me? I stress again that I am interested in the infinitely generated case. Thank you.

Comment: What's is a "saturated submodule"? What's a "family of non-intersecting submodules"?

Comment: A submodule $\mathbf{W}\subset\mathbf{V}$ is called saturated in $\mathbf{V}$ if $rx\in\mathbf{W}$ implies $x\in\mathbf{W}$ for all $x\in\mathbf{V}$, $0\neq r\in R$.By non-intersecting I mean pairwise trivially intersecting.

Comment: Could you say where you found the information in the first place?

Comment: In what I have written there is no information in the sense that I have no references for it. That's exactly what I am asking for. I have written " If I understand it correctly" which means that this need not be true. I can bring arguments in favour of this but that would be lengthy. Start from the extended module $\mathbf{V}\otimes_RQ(R)$.

Comment: There exist indecomposable torsion-free abelian groups of arbitrary large rank.  This seems to contradict your claim, as it would imply in particular that all indecomposable torsion-free abelian groups have rank $1$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Good thinking! Unless $R$ contains a field, I probably cannot disentangle rank 1 submodules to make them maximal indecomposable. I should have written rank 1 instead of indecomposable. I will edit the question.

Comment: Now you seem to claim that $V$ is a direct sum of rank $1$-submodules. This still won't work, by the same example as before. In fact, for every PID $R$ which is not a DVR, there exist indecomposable torsion-free $R$-modules of rank 2. (See Kaplansky, Infinite Abelian Groups, Thm. 19). So, if you take $R=K[X]$ for a field $K$, you see that even if $R$ includes a field it does not help.